# Почему получается разный результат DataSet

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему в коде при добавлении в таблицу объектов в типа DataRow по очереди все работает нормально. Если добавить с использованием перегруженного метода Add(params []  DataRow) то работает непонятно как. Во-первых выводит не значение в ячейке строки, а ToString() объекта DataRow, а во-вторых, не видит ничего выше Rows[0]. То есть Rows[1] уже говорит, что его нету, как так ? Вот код

```
SqlCeDataAdapter sCEdata = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from [Cats]", @"Data Source=C:\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\Data.sdf");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sCEdata.Fill(ds);
            DataRow dr1 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            DataRow dr2 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            DataRow dr3 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            dr1["Name"] = "Pavel"; dr1["Hozain"] = "Sergey"; dr1["Note"] = "Starii";
            dr2["Name"] = "Gleb"; dr2["Hozain"] = "Inga"; dr2["Note"] = "Tupaya";
            dr3["Name"] = "Dusia"; dr3["Hozain"] = "Olga"; dr3["Note"] = "Zlaya";

            //ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2); ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr3);

            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DataRow[] { dr1, dr2, dr3 });
            Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[0].Rows[1][1]);
```

Если расскоментировать строку с поочередным добавлением, то все ок (при этом закоментить добавление в виде массива). При чем не важно как я добавляю к params, как массив или через запятую.
Почему так ??

ПС Сама таблица, пустая, только лишь содержит имена столбцов. Это я про ту таблицу которая в первой строчке кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание, перегруженная версия [DataRowCollection.Add(params Object[] values);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx) принимает в качестве параметра, "**Массив объектов, который используется для создания новой строки**" в данном случае, под массивом объектов понимается не массив DataRow, а массив тех элементов, из которых состоит строка, т.е. ячеек.

Comment: Ах, точно !! Спасибо огромное, действительно